# how can i insert dynamic fields of a form in django into database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form with checkbox inputs the  number of inputs is dynamic because i get  it from the database,in my form i might have 2 or 3 or N .. checkboxes. From these input the user will check some or all of them and then he click the submit button.

The problem is that only one input is saved into database

```
<form method="post"  action="createQcm">
{% csrf_token %}

{% for mati in quest %}

<INPUT type="checkbox" value ="{{mati.id_question }}" name="choix" >
{{mati.questionA }}</input></br></br>
{% endfor %}


<input type="hidden" name="s" value="{{idQ}}" readonly>
```

the view:

```
def createQcm(request):
    q=request.POST["choix"]
    r=request.POST["s"]
    rep = contenir(idQuestion=q,idQuiz=r)
    rep.save()

    return render(request,'myblog/subject.html')
```

How  can  I save them all?

Comment: What is your data structured like? Perhaps post your `models.py` and show what your desired output is?